# Как XML файл прочитать?

Tags: c#, winforms, xml, datagridview, dataset

Подскажите, как прочитать такой файл, в одну или несколько DataGridView таблиц и чтобы данные можно было бы связать.

Это файл продажи, в котором указан Клиент, номер счёта и т.д. и детальные строки что было продано.

Читаю в 3 разные таблицы, но как то думаю можно всё в одну и связать между собой. в моём случае непонятно какому клиенту какой заказ.

```
{
    //Create xml reader
    XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(@"D:\MyDocuments\Desktop\export_import.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    //Read xml to dataset
    dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFile);
    //Pass empdetails table to datagridview datasource
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["klientas"];
    //Close xml reader
    xmlFile.Close();
}

{
    //xml reader
    XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(@"D:\MyDocuments\Desktop\export_import.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    //Read xml to dataset
    dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFile);
    //Pass empdetails table to datagridview datasource
    dg_pard.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["pardavimoRezervavimas"];
    //Close xml reader
    xmlFile.Close();
}

{
    //xml reader
    XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(@"D:\MyDocuments\Desktop\export_import.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    //Read xml to dataset
    dataSet.ReadXml(xmlFile);
    //Pass empdetails table to datagridview datasource
    dg_pard1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["eilute"];
    //Close xml reader
    xmlFile.Close();
}
```

---

Прикрепляю какой должен быть результат:

[image: Общая таблица]

[image: Детальная таблица]

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fvsdata>
    <klientas>
        <kodas>MUST_LT</kodas>
        <pavadinimas>Lina XXXX</pavadinimas>
        <adresas>Adresas TV</adresas>
        <rusis>LT</rusis>
        <pozymis1>ESHOP</pozymis1>
        <pozymis2>ESHOP_FIZ</pozymis2>
        <pozymis3>ESHOP</pozymis3>
        <pvm_kodas>21PVM</pvm_kodas>
        <im_kodas/>
    </klientas>
    <pardavimoRezervavimas>
        <serija>MUST</serija>
        <dokumentas>5239</dokumentas>
        <klientas>MUST_LT</klientas>
        <data>2021.10.25</data>
        <valiuta>EUR</valiuta>
        <imp_param>ESHOP</imp_param>
        <pavadinimas3>KRED</pavadinimas3>
        <pavadinimas5>DPD</pavadinimas5>
        <operacijaDet>
            <eilute>
                <sandelis>DISTRIB_S</sandelis>
                <tipas>1</tipas>
                <kodas>00000009</kodas>
                <pavadinimas>Kavos kapsulės Ristretto, Dolce Gusto® aparatui, 16vnt</pavadinimas>
                <kiekis>3</kiekis>
                <suma_v>9.110000</suma_v>
                <suma_l>9.110000</suma_l>
                <suma_pvmv>1.92</suma_pvmv>
                <suma_pvml>1.92</suma_pvml>
                <suma_nv/>
                <suma_nl/>
                <objektas2>DISTRIBUCI</objektas2>
                <objektas3/>
                <objektas6>E_MUST</objektas6>
            </eilute>
            <eilute>
                <sandelis>DISTRIB_S</sandelis>
                <tipas>1</tipas>
                <kodas>00000008</kodas>
                <pavadinimas>Kavos kapsulės Cremoso, Dolce Gusto® aparatui, 16vnt</pavadinimas>
                <kiekis>4</kiekis>
                <suma_v>11.340000</suma_v>
                <suma_l>11.340000</suma_l>
                <suma_pvmv>2.38</suma_pvmv>
                <suma_pvml>2.38</suma_pvml>
                <suma_nv/>
                <suma_nl/>
                <objektas2>DISTRIBUCI</objektas2>
                <objektas3/>
                <objektas6>E_MUST</objektas6>
            </eilute>
            <eilute>
                <sandelis/>
                <tipas>2</tipas>
                <kodas>LOGISTIKOS_P</kodas>
                <pavadinimas>Logistikos paslaugos</pavadinimas>
                <kiekis>100</kiekis>
                <suma_v>1.570000</suma_v>
                <suma_l>1.570000</suma_l>
                <suma_pvmv>0.33</suma_pvmv>
                <suma_pvml>0.33</suma_pvml>
                <suma_nv/>
                <suma_nl/>
                <objektas2>DISTRIBUCI</objektas2>
                <objektas3>LOG PASL</objektas3>
                <objektas6>E_MUST</objektas6>
            </eilute>
        </operacijaDet>
    </pardavimoRezervavimas>
    <klientas>
        <kodas>MUST_LT</kodas>
        <pavadinimas>Vida XXXX</pavadinimas>
        <adresas>Adresas TV</adresas>
        <rusis>LT</rusis>
        <pozymis1>ESHOP</pozymis1>
        <pozymis2>ESHOP_FIZ</pozymis2>
        <pozymis3>ESHOP</pozymis3>
        <pvm_kodas>21PVM</pvm_kodas>
        <im_kodas/>
    </klientas>
    <pardavimoRezervavimas>
        <serija>MUST</serija>
        <dokumentas>5240</dokumentas>
        <klientas>MUST_LT</klientas>
        <data>2021.10.25</data>
        <valiuta>EUR</valiuta>
        <imp_param>ESHOP</imp_param>
        <pavadinimas3>KRED</pavadinimas3>
        <pavadinimas5>OMNIVA</pavadinimas5>
        <operacijaDet>
            <eilute>
                <sandelis>DISTRIB_S</sandelis>
                <tipas>1</tipas>
                <kodas>00000013</kodas>
                <pavadinimas>Karšto šokolado kapsulės, Dolce Gusto® aparatui, 16vnt</pavadinimas>
                <kiekis>3</kiekis>
                <suma_v>7.900000</suma_v>
                <suma_l>7.900000</suma_l>
                <suma_pvmv>1.66</suma_pvmv>
                <suma_pvml>1.66</suma_pvml>
                <suma_nv/>
                <suma_nl/>
                <objektas2>DISTRIBUCI</objektas2>
                <objektas3/>
                <objektas6>E_MUST</objektas6>
            </eilute>
            <eilute>
                <sandelis/>
                <tipas>2</tipas>
                <kodas>LOGISTIKOS_P</kodas>
                <pavadinimas>Logistikos paslaugos</pavadinimas>
                <kiekis>100</kiekis>
                <suma_v>1.570000</suma_v>
                <suma_l>1.570000</suma_l>
                <suma_pvmv>0.33</suma_pvmv>
                <suma_pvml>0.33</suma_pvml>
                <suma_nv/>
                <suma_nl/>
                <objektas2>DISTRIBUCI</objektas2>
                <objektas3>LOG PASL</objektas3>
                <objektas6>E_MUST</objektas6>
            </eilute>
        </operacijaDet>
    </pardavimoRezervavimas>
    <klientas>
        <kodas>MUST_LT</kodas>
        <pavadinimas>Rima XXXXX</pavadinimas>
        <adresas>Adresas TV</adresas>
        <rusis>LT</rusis>
        <pozymis1>ESHOP</pozymis1>
        <pozymis2>ESHOP_FIZ</pozymis2>
        <pozymis3>ESHOP</pozymis3>
        <pvm_kodas>21PVM</pvm_kodas>
        <im_kodas/>
    </klientas>
    <pardavimoRezervavimas>
        <serija>MUST</serija>
        <dokumentas>5241</dokumentas>
        <klientas>MUST_LT</klientas>
        <data>2021.10.25</data>
        <valiuta>EUR</valiuta>
        <imp_param>ESHOP</imp_param>
        <pavadinimas3>KRED</pavadinimas3>
        <pavadinimas5>OMNIVA</pavadinimas5>
        <operacijaDet>
            <eilute>
                <sandelis>DISTRIB_S</sandelis>
                <tipas>1</tipas>
                <kodas>00000013</kodas>
                <pavadinimas>Karšto šokolado kapsulės, Dolce Gusto® aparatui, 16vnt</pavadinimas>
                <kiekis>2</kiekis>
                <suma_v>5.260000</suma_v>
                <suma_l>5.260000</suma_l>
                <suma_pvmv>1.11</suma_pvmv>
                <suma_pvml>1.11</suma_pvml>
                <suma_nv/>
                <suma_nl/>
                <objektas2>DISTRIBUCI</objektas2>
                <objektas3/>
                <objektas6>E_MUST</objektas6>
            </eilute>
            <eilute>
                <sandelis>DISTRIB_S</sandelis>
                <tipas>1</tipas>
                <kodas>00000016</kodas>
                <pavadinimas>Kavos kapsulės Cappuccino Barista, Dolce Gusto® aparatui, 16vnt</pavadinimas>
                <kiekis>1</kiekis>
                <suma_v>2.830000</suma_v>
                <suma_l>2.830000</suma_l>
                <suma_pvmv>0.6</suma_pvmv>
                <suma_pvml>0.6</suma_pvml>
                <suma_nv/>
                <suma_nl/>
                <objektas2>DISTRIBUCI</objektas2>
                <objektas3/>
                <objektas6>E_MUST</objektas6>
            </eilute>
            <eilute>
                <sandelis>DISTRIB_S</sandelis>
                <tipas>1</tipas>
                <kodas>00000019</kodas>
                <pavadinimas>Kavos kapsulės Latte Macchiato, Dolce Gusto® aparatui, 16vnt</pavadinimas>
                <kiekis>1</kiekis>
                <suma_v>2.630000</suma_v>
                <suma_l>2.630000</suma_l>
                <suma_pvmv>0.56</suma_pvmv>
                <suma_pvml>0.56</suma_pvml>
                <suma_nv/>
                <suma_nl/>
                <objektas2>DISTRIBUCI</objektas2>
                <objektas3/>
                <objektas6>E_MUST</objektas6>
            </eilute>
            <eilute>
                <sandelis>DISTRIB_S</sandelis>
                <tipas>1</tipas>
                <kodas>00000035</kodas>
                <pavadinimas>Ekologiškos arbatos kapsulės, juodoji su citrina, Dolce Gusto® aparatui, 16 vnt.</pavadinimas>
                <kiekis>1</kiekis>
                <suma_v>2.630000</suma_v>
                <suma_l>2.630000</suma_l>
                <suma_pvmv>0.56</suma_pvmv>
                <suma_pvml>0.56</suma_pvml>
                <suma_nv/>
                <suma_nl/>
                <objektas2>DISTRIBUCI</objektas2>
                <objektas3/>
                <objektas6>E_MUST</objektas6>
            </eilute>
            <eilute>
                <sandelis/>
                <tipas>2</tipas>
                <kodas>LOGISTIKOS_P</kodas>
                <pavadinimas>Logistikos paslaugos</pavadinimas>
                <kiekis>100</kiekis>
                <suma_v>1.570000</suma_v>
                <suma_l>1.570000</suma_l>
                <suma_pvmv>0.33</suma_pvmv>
                <suma_pvml>0.33</suma_pvml>
                <suma_nv/>
                <suma_nl/>
                <objektas2>DISTRIBUCI</objektas2>
                <objektas3>LOG PASL</objektas3>
                <objektas6>E_MUST</objektas6>
            </eilute>
        </operacijaDet>
    </pardavimoRezervavimas>
    <klientas>
        <kodas>MUST_LV</kodas>
        <pavadinimas>Ekaterina XXXX</pavadinimas>
        <adresas>Adresas TV</adresas>
        <rusis>LV_EE</rusis>
        <pozymis1>ESHOP</pozymis1>
        <pozymis2>ESHOP_FIZ</pozymis2>
        <pozymis3>ESHOP</pozymis3>
        <pvm_kodas>21PVM</pvm_kodas>
        <im_kodas/>
    </klientas>
    <pardavimoRezervavimas>
        <serija>MUST</serija>
        <dokumentas>5242</dokumentas>
        <klientas>MUST_LV</klientas>
        <data>2021.10.25</data>
        <valiuta>EUR</valiuta>
        <imp_param>ESHOP</imp_param>
        <pavadinimas3>KRED</pavadinimas3>
        <pavadinimas5>DPD</pavadinimas5>
        <operacijaDet>
            <eilute>
                <sandelis>DISTRIB_S</sandelis>
                <tipas>1</tipas>
                <kodas>00000008</kodas>
                <pavadinimas>Kafija kapsulas Cremoso – saderīgas ar Dolce Gusto® aparātiem, 16 gab.</pavadinimas>
                <kiekis>1</kiekis>
                <suma_v>2.830000</suma_v>
                <suma_l>2.830000</suma_l>
                <suma_pvmv>0.6</suma_pvmv>
                <suma_pvml>0.6</suma_pvml>
                <suma_nv/>
                <suma_nl/>
                <objektas2>DISTRIBUCI</objektas2>
                <objektas3/>
                <objektas6>E_MUST</objektas6>
            </eilute>
            <eilute>
                <sandelis>DISTRIB_S</sandelis>
                <tipas>1</tipas>
                <kodas>00000027</kodas>
                <pavadinimas>Organiskās kapsulas Earl Grey tēja – saderīgas ar Dolce Gusto® aparātiem, 16gab.</pavadinimas>
                <kiekis>1</kiekis>
                <suma_v>4.050000</suma_v>
                <suma_l>4.050000</suma_l>
                <suma_pvmv>0.85</suma_pvmv>
                <suma_pvml>0.85</suma_pvml>
                <suma_nv/>
                <suma_nl/>
                <objektas2>DISTRIBUCI</objektas2>
                <objektas3/>
                <objektas6>E_MUST</objektas6>
            </eilute>
            <eilute>
                <sandelis/>
                <tipas>2</tipas>
                <kodas>LOGISTIKOS_P</kodas>
                <pavadinimas>Logistikos paslaugos</pavadinimas>
                <kiekis>100</kiekis>
                <suma_v>1.570000</suma_v>
                <suma_l>1.570000</suma_l>
                <suma_pvmv>0.33</suma_pvmv>
                <suma_pvml>0.33</suma_pvml>
                <suma_nv/>
                <suma_nl/>
                <objektas2>DISTRIBUCI</objektas2>
                <objektas3>LOG PASL</objektas3>
                <objektas6>E_MUST</objektas6>
            </eilute>
        </operacijaDet>
    </pardavimoRezervavimas>
</fvsdata>
```

Comment: Я бы xml переобразовал в json, а потом json в C# объекты и список объектов уже легко забиндить в datagridview

Comment: @AlAvenger - зачем промежуточный json?

Comment: Предоставьте xml в виде текста.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov работать с xml ужасно неудобно, если у придет xml который попытаешься преобразовать в класс и это не получится - исключение, если же у тебя есть варианты xml (к примеру один если всё ок, другой если ошибка), то надо мучаться и с этим. Если же будет 2 таких же json, то один из объектов будет просто null

Comment: @AlAvenger -  _получишь исключение_ - нет, я получу тот результат, который мне нужен. Работа с xml ничем принципиально не отличается от работы с json. / В данном случае я не вижу необходимости перегонять из одного формата в другой, а затем в объекты c#.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412186/read-xml-file-as-dataset

Comment: Узлы в показанном xml идут по очереди "klientas" и "pardavimoRezervavimas". Ближние соседи составляют пару? Если да, то за такой формат нужно бить ногами. Предлагаю начать с изменения формата xml. То, что составляет единое целое, должно быть вложено в один узел. Тогда данные будет легко парсить.

Comment: Чтобы было понятно, о чём я говорю: узлы "eilute" вложены в "operacijaDet", который находится в "pardavimoRezervavimas" - так сразу понятно, что к чему относится. Это правильный формат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делаем два класса-модели:

```
class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Serija { get; set; }
    public string Dokumentas { get; set; }
    public string Pavadinimas1 { get; set; }
    public string Pavadinimas2 { get; set; }
    public string Pavadinimas3 { get; set; }
    public string Pavadinimas4 { get; set; }
    public string Pavadinimas5 { get; set; }
    public string Klientas { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public string Valiuta { get; set; }
}

class Detail
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EilNr { get; set; }
    public string Sandelis { get; set; }
    public int Tipas { get; set; }
    public string Kodas { get; set; }
    public string Pavadinimas { get; set; }
    public int Kiekis { get; set; }
    public decimal SumaV { get; set; }
    public decimal SumaL { get; set; }
    public decimal SumaPvmv { get; set; }
    public decimal SumaPvml { get; set; }
}
```

Добавьте недостающие свойства сами.

Пример приложения с загрузкой данных из xml.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WinForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DoubleBufferedDataGridView dataGridViewMaster;
        DoubleBufferedDataGridView dataGridViewDetail;

        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
            this.Size = new Size(1200, 800);

            var xml = XElement.Load("test.xml");

            //var klientas = xml.Elements("klientas").ToList();
            var pardavimoRezervavimas = xml.Elements("pardavimoRezervavimas").ToList();

            var clients = pardavimoRezervavimas.Select((x, i) => new Client
            {
                Id = i + 1,
                Serija = x.Element("serija").Value,
                Dokumentas = x.Element("dokumentas").Value,
                Pavadinimas1 = x.Element("pavadinimas1")?.Value,
                Pavadinimas2 = x.Element("pavadinimas2")?.Value,
                Pavadinimas3 = x.Element("pavadinimas3")?.Value,
                Pavadinimas4 = x.Element("pavadinimas4")?.Value,
                Pavadinimas5 = x.Element("pavadinimas5")?.Value,
                Klientas = x.Element("klientas").Value,
                Data = (DateTime)x.Element("data"),
                Valiuta = x.Element("valiuta").Value,
            }).ToList();

            var details = pardavimoRezervavimas.SelectMany((x, i) =>
                    x.Elements("operacijaDet").Elements("eilute").Select(eilute => new { eilute, i }))
                .Select((a, j) => new Detail
                {
                    Id = a.i + 1,
                    EilNr = j + 1,
                    Sandelis = a.eilute.Element("sandelis").Value,
                    Tipas = (int)a.eilute.Element("tipas"),
                    Kodas = a.eilute.Element("kodas").Value,
                    Pavadinimas = a.eilute.Element("pavadinimas").Value,
                    Kiekis = (int)a.eilute.Element("kiekis"),
                    SumaV = (decimal)a.eilute.Element("suma_v"),
                    SumaL = (decimal)a.eilute.Element("suma_l"),
                    SumaPvmv = (decimal)a.eilute.Element("suma_pvmv"),
                    SumaPvml = (decimal)a.eilute.Element("suma_pvml")
                })
                .ToList();

            dataGridViewMaster = new DoubleBufferedDataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top, Height = 300 };
            dataGridViewMaster.DataSource = clients;

            dataGridViewDetail = new DoubleBufferedDataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Bottom, Height = 400 };
            dataGridViewDetail.DataSource = details;
        }
    }
}
```

Я думаю, не составит труда по аналогии добавить недостающие данные.

---

Грид с двойной буферизацией:

```
class DoubleBufferedDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override bool DoubleBuffered => true;
}
```